# If Then not working

Tags: active-directory

I've searched a lot about this problem, but I haven't found anything specific to this case. I'm trying to run a script that grabs all hosts from AD, then checks each one for a specific file. Two txt files are created, one with and one without. The problem I'm having is that all host names are added to the 'without' file and the 'with' file is empty, but I know for a fact that both lists should have hosts listed. I know the loop is working because all the host names are listed, but it fails to apply the if/then check. I apologize for the crudity of my script, I'm VERY new to this. I would GREATLY appreciate any tips...

```
Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

Dim cn
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
cn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Dim cmd
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
Dim ou
ou = "DC=mydomain,DC=COM"
cmd.CommandText =   "SELECT name " & _
                    "FROM 'LDAP://" & ou & "' " & _
                    "WHERE objectClass='computer' " & _
                    "ORDER BY name"
cmd.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
cmd.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

Const ForAppending = 8
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim yesFile
Set yesFile = fso.OpenTextFile("pcswithsw.txt", ForAppending, True)
Dim noFile
Set noFile = fso.OpenTextFile("pcswithoutsw.txt", ForAppending, True)
Dim rs
Set rs = cmd.Execute
strComputer = rs(0)
rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From CIM_DataFile Where Name = 'C:\\somefile.exe'")
        If colFiles.Count = 0 Then
            noFile.WriteLine rs(0)
        Else
            yesFile.WriteLine rs(0)
        End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

yesFile.Close
noFile.Close
Set yesFile = Nothing
Set noFile = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally. I loaded the list of hosts into an array, then fed the array to the If/Then statement. It runs slowly, but the majority of the processing time is the script waiting for non-existent hosts to reply (need to clean up AD).

```
Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
Const ForAppending = 8

Dim hostArray()

Dim cn
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
cn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Dim cmd
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
Dim ou
ou = "DC=mydomain,DC=COM"
cmd.CommandText =   "SELECT name " & _
                    "FROM 'LDAP://" & ou & "' " & _
                    "WHERE objectClass='computer' " & _
                    "ORDER BY name"
cmd.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
cmd.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim outFile
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile("computers.txt", ForAppending, True)
Dim yesFile
Set yesFile = fso.OpenTextFile("pcswithsw.txt", ForAppending, True)
Dim noFile
Set noFile = fso.OpenTextFile("pcswithoutsw.txt", ForAppending, True)

Dim j
j=0
Dim rs
Set rs = cmd.Execute
rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF
    REDIM PRESERVE hostArray(j)
    for i = 0 to rs.EOF
    hostArray(j)=rs(0)
    outFile.WriteLine rs(0)
    rs.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
    next
Loop

    For Each strComputer in hostArray
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From CIM_DataFile Where Name = 'C:\\folder\\subfolder\\file.ext'")
            If colFiles.Count = 0 Then
                noFile.WriteLine strComputer
            Else
                yesFile.WriteLine strComputer
            End If
    Next

yesFile.Close
noFile.Close
Set yesFile = Nothing
Set noFile = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
msgbox("All done")
```